# Incompatible pointer type - C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have this structure of structs, presented in this code:

```
typedef void* DataP;
typedef struct Table* TableP;
typedef const void* ConstKeyP;

typedef struct DataPointer
{
    DataP dataP;
    ConstKeyP key;
}DataPointer;

typedef struct HashTableSet
{
DataPointer *hashSet[MAX_ROW_ELEMENTS];
}HashTableSet;

typedef struct HashTableSet *HashTable;

typedef struct Table
{
int size, d;
HashTable hashTable;
}Table;
```

That is the structure.
Now here is the function that creates the hash table -

```
TableP createTable(size_t tableSize)
{
TableP tableP = (TableP)malloc(sizeof(Table));
HashTable table = (HashTable)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
tableP->d = 1;
tableP->size = tableSize;
nullTable(tableP);
return tableP;
}
```

where nullTable is a function that i want to both to give memory for the actual sets and also give null initial value:

```
void nullTable(TableP tableP)
{
HashTable hashTable = tableP->hashTable;
int i = 0;
for(;  i < tableP->size; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    HashTableSet *hashTableSet = (HashTableSet*)malloc(sizeof(HashTableSet));
    for (; j < MAX_ROW_ELEMENTS ; ++j)
    {

        DataPointer *data = (DataPointer*)malloc(sizeof(HashTableSet));
        hashTableSet->hashSet[j] = data;
    }
    hashTable[i] = *hashTableSet;
    //hashTable->hashSet = *hashTableSet;
    hashTable += sizeof(HashTableSet);

    }
}
```

First question comes up here - in the last lines of nullTable, i am trying to "jump" my pointer of hashTable to the next set memory. meaning i have allocated all the space i need for a set, pointed my hashTable[i] at it, and then i added sizeof(HashTableSet) to hashTable because i want it to get to the next "spot" for another hashTableSet. This already fills like i am doing something wrong.

Next i reach to my real problem of understanding how this pointer iterating works in this function:

```
DataP removeData(TableP table, const void* key)
{
TableP tableP = table;
int cell = table->hfun(key, table->size);
HashTable hashTable = table->hashTable;
HashTableSet *setPtr = hashTable->hashSet;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int d = 1;
while(d < tableP->d)
{
    for (; i < MAX_ROW_ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        if (table->fcomp(setPtr->hashSet[i]->key, key) == 0)
        {
            DataP dataP = setPtr->hashSet[i]->dataP;
            setPtr->hashSet[i] = NULL;
            table->freeKey((void*)key);
            return dataP;
        }
    }
    setPtr *= 2;
    i = 0;
}
return NULL;
}
```

I want setPtr to point at the first HashTableSet of my table. But i get this error message:

```
 warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
 HashTableSet *setPtr = hashTable->hashSet;
```

I am also having a problem understanding how to take setPtr to the next hashSet, assuming that i managed to actually define setPtr correctly for my needs.

Comment: The type of `setPtr` is `HashTableSet*`, but the type of what is converted from `hashTable->hashSet` is `DataPointer**`. Here is the mismatch.

Comment: Stop using casts and pointer typedefs. It will make your code easier to read (and help the compiler diagnose problems).

Comment: .. or at least be consistent with naming: `ConstKeyP key;` --> `ConstKeyP keyP;` and `typedef struct HashTableSet *HashTable;` --> `typedef struct HashTableSet *HashTableP;` and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your definitions:

```
typedef void* DataP;
typedef struct Table* TableP;
typedef const void* ConstKeyP;

typedef struct DataPointer
{
    DataP dataP;
    ConstKeyP key;
}DataPointer;

typedef struct HashTableSet
{
DataPointer *hashSet[MAX_ROW_ELEMENTS];
}HashTableSet;

typedef struct HashTableSet *HashTable;

typedef struct Table
{
int size, d;
HashTable hashTable;
}Table;
```

From your code:

```
HashTable hashTable = tableP->hashTable;
HashTableSet *setPtr = hashTable->hashSet;
```

So `hashTable` of type `HashTable` which is `struct HashTableSet*`. So far so good.
The next line is the problem:
    HashTableSet *setPtr = hashTable->hashSet;

`hashTable->hashSet` is NOT of type HashTableSet!

This will work:

```
DataP removeData(TableP table, const void* key) 
  { 
      TableP tableP = table; 
      int cell = table->hfun(key, table->size); 
      HashTable hashTable = table->hashTable; 
      /*  
       * See change in the following line: 
       * Before the change you were trying to assign type  
       * `HashSet` into type `HashTableSet*`, this will   
       */ 
      HashTableSet *setPtr = hashTable;                                                         
      int i = 0;         
      int j = 0;         
      int d = 1;         
      while(d < tableP->d)         
      {         
          for (; i < MAX_ROW_ELEMENTS; i++)     
          {     
              if (table->fcomp(setPtr->hashSet[i]->key, key) == 0) 
              { 
                  DataP dataP = setPtr->hashSet[i]->dataP;
                  setPtr->hashSet[i] = NULL;
                  table->freeKey((void*)key);
                  return dataP;
              } 
          }     
          setPtr *= 2;     
          i = 0;     
      }         
      return NULL;         
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, i think i get it now. I have a question - i got now a problem with setPtr *= 2. If my goal is to get to the next exponential number of hashSet, say i have setPtr point at my 1st set, i want the next iteration to point to the second, the next iteration to point at the 4th, then 8th, exc.. What will be the correct way to increment my setPtr?

Comment: Hi Eyzuky, this is a different question, and broader than one that can be answered in a comment. If your original question has an accepted answer, please mark it as answered and ask the new question in a new thread.

Comment: @Eyzuky `for (i=1; i < number_of_sets; i*=2) { /*do some stuff */ setPtr +=i;}`

Comment: Of course there's always @KlasLindbäck to give a percise answer to your second question too (; +1

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! i learned a lot from your answer. Having said that, there is still so much to learn :)